# Excel function with custom range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Question 1: In Excel, I want to use the XIRR formula on a discontinous range, e.g. I have dates in cells B3:F3 and cash flows in cells B6:F6. I need to put "-" before the first cash flow, but the formula below does not work
= XIRR((-B6,C6:F6),B3:F3)
So the only way I can think of is to copy all the cash flows and put - against the first one. Can I use XIRR without having to copy the numbers so that the first cash flow is negative? Please see

[image: Excel Screen shot]

Question 2: I want to use goal-seek in VBA that loops through a series of data in rows. Goal-seek can fail sometimes but if a reasonably close start value is provided then it is more likely to converge. This is the reason I use XIRR function to provide a close estimate. I have written a macro to do this but it copies formulae in Excel and then paste results, so it runs slow when data is large.
How can I amend this macro so that all this operation is done in VBA (including calling Excel formula) and only the final results from goal-seek are pasted into cells A6:A8?

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("B11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-5]C"
    Range("B11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B11:B13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-5]C"
    Range("C11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C11:F13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=XIRR(RC[1]:RC[5],R3C2:R3C6)"
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A11:A13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(RC[-4]:RC[-1],(1+RC[-6])^(-R4C[-4]:R4C[-1]))-RC[-5]"
    Range("G6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G6:G8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Row = 6 To 8
    Range("G" & Row).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("A" & Row)
Next Row


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have O365, you can calculate `XIRR` with the following formula:

```
=XIRR(Returns*IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Returns))=1,-1,1),Dates)
```

This will multiply the first `Return` by -1, and the others by 1.

*IF you have an earlier version of Excel, without the `SEQUENCE` function, try:*

```
=XIRR(Returns*IF(COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1,1):INDEX($1:$1,1,COUNT(Returns)))=1,-1,1),Dates)
```

Comment: @Sam What do you mean by *"doesn't works"*?.  It certainly returns a valid result on your data as posted.  I assumed that you would understand that `Returns` refers to `B6:F6` on your screenshot, and `Dates` to `B3:F3`

Comment: I am using this formula on the data posted =XIRR(B6:F6*IF(COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1,1):INDEX($1:$1,1,COUNT(B6:F6)))=1,-1,1),B3:F3)  and it returns #VALUE!

Comment: @Sam  For me it returns `1.180279291`  which is the same result that `XIRR` returns if I make the first entry `-100`.  Try entering the formula as an array formula by holding down `ctrl` while hitting `shift-enter`.  Some earlier versions of Excel may require that.

Comment: Thank you @Ron Rosenfeld Entering the formula as an array did the trick. Would you know how I can use this in VBA? VBA allows calling Excel functions as Application.WorksheetFunction.Xirr    however, it probably requires defining the same range in a different way

Comment: @Sam Not sure I understand what you mean.  Your posted code just shows you writing a formula to the worksheet. Just change the formula that you are writing but use the `.FormulaArray` property,

Comment: In the code I am copying and pasting a formula to the worksheet. What I want to do is to read the data from the worksheet but apply the formula directly in VBA and copy paste the result into the worksheet. So all calculations are done in the VBA and end result ported to the worksheet

Comment: One example could be something like the lines below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic

Sub UseFunction() 
 Dim myRange As Range 
 Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10") 
 answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange) 
 MsgBox answer 
End Sub

Comment: @Sam That's quite a bit different from your original question. But `WorksheetFunction.XIRR` will take arrays as arguments, so all you need to do is read the `Values` into an array, and change the sign of the first item. Then use that array for the Values argument.